# In a shop there are 10 different types of beers. How many ways are to buy 6 (not necessarily different) beers?

Tags: probability, combinations

In a shop there are 10 different types of beers. How many ways are to buy 6  (not necessarily different) beers?

Intuitively, the answer should be 10^6. Is this correct?

Comment: Since any of the beers can be chosen more than once, there are 10 choices for each of the six beers.  So, $10^6$ is right on the money.

Comment: 10^6 is not the right answer.

For example, say that you buy 3 bottles of beer A and 3 bottles of beer B. Picking the order ABBABA is not any different than BABBAA.

Comment: @Jed is correct. So should the answer be "someNumber Choose 6"? I'm not sure what that number should be (we are only given that there are 10 types of beer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you keep 10 distinct cartons for each type of beer.

Today you want to replenish your stock by adding a total of 6 beers in any which carton(s).

This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, which yields the answer

$\dbinom{6+10-1}{10-1} = \dbinom{15}{9} = 5005$

Comment: Thanks @true blue anil. Could you explain more about how you apply the starts and bars theorem into this problem? why do we add a total of 6 beers?

Comment: We add 6 beers because we are to buy 6 beers ! With $x_i$ representing the $i_{th}$ type of beer, you may recognize it better as $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... +x_{10} = 6, x_i \ge0$